# Can't click invisible view Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

i want to make an x & o game for Android so i created my layout using linear layouts. I also have a function to make the letters start from the sky, but if the image is invisible(i need the board to be empty at the beginning) i cant click it to make it appear. I also logged to see if the function is actioned, and it is not at all.

This is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_x_me_www" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_x_me_www" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_x_me_www" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_x_me_www" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_x_me_www" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_x_me_www" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_x_me_www" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_x_me_www" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_x_me_www" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_board_me_www" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is my main activity:

````
    private lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
    // 0 - cross, 1 - circle
    var activePlayer = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR)

    }

    fun dropIn(view:View){
        val slotImage = view as ImageView
        slotImage.translationY = -2000f
        if(activePlayer==0) {
            slotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_x_me_www)
            slotImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            Log.e("x","merge")
            activePlayer = 1
        }else {
            slotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_o_me_www)
            slotImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            activePlayer = 0
            Log.e("o","merge")
        }
        slotImage.animate().translationYBy(2000f).rotation(1800f).setDuration(500)
    }```
````

Comment: can you use alpha 0f and 1f instead of invisible and visible?